# JavaScript DOM - how to add class to each <img> and add <p> above each immage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-lists

I have a problem with adding class to each `img` and `p` doesn't display anything for each image. Here is my code...

```
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Dope",
        img: "pic/dope.jpg",
        link: "dope.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "The Do Over",
        img: "pic/The_Do-Over.png",
        link: "The_Do-Over.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Deadpool",
        img: "pic/Deadpool.jpg",
        link: "Deadpool.html"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "Johnny English Reborn",
        img: "pic/johnny_english_reborn.jpg",
        link: "johnny_english_reborn.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

function createList() {

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {


        //create li
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = list[i].id;

        //create paragraph -------------- doesnt desplay anything--problem
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.title = list[i].title;
        li.appendChild(p);

        //create image
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = list[i].img;
        img.title = list[i].title;

        //adding class
        img.class = "image";

        //create href
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = list[i].link;    
        a.appendChild(img);
        li.appendChild(a);

        //append this li to the ul
        ul.appendChild(li);

    }

    //outside the loop, append once the ul to the wrapper
    input.appendChild(ul);
    console.log(ul);


};

createList();
```

Comment: is this an external js script ?

Comment: I think the problem is the input. It is not a block element so you cannot add  child into it. See sample I used a div https://jsfiddle.net/6bomaqo1/

Answer (score 2):

In plain javascript, class name is added using attribute *className*

add class like this

```
img.className = "image";
```

I have updated the jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/6bomaqo1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the link https://plnkr.co/edit/wjlaazFaF1F23a6WJlN2?p=preview

once the html created then only you have to call the function before creating the dom if u take get elemnt by id it wont append and also the class name i addedd please check

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <input id="input" />
    <div id="newid" > </div>
      <script>

    var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Dope",
        img: "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png",
        link: "dope.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "The Do Over",
        img: "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png",
        link: "The_Do-Over.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Deadpool",
        img: "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png",
        link: "Deadpool.html"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "Johnny English Reborn",
        img: "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png",
        link: "johnny_english_reborn.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

function createList() {

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {


        //create li
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = list[i].id;

        //create paragraph -------------- doesnt desplay anything--problem
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.title = list[i].title;
        p.innerHTML = list[i].title;
        li.appendChild(p);

        //create image
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = list[i].img;
        img.title = list[i].title;

        //adding class
        img.className = "newimage";

        //create href
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = list[i].link;    
        a.appendChild(img);
        li.appendChild(a);

        //append this li to the ul
        ul.appendChild(li);

    }

    //outside the loop, append once the ul to the wrapper
    console.log(ul);
   document.getElementById("newid").appendChild(ul);


};

createList();
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```